# Error in Bluetooth.enable: TypeError: Cannot read property 'startActivityForResult' of undefined

Tags: javascript, android, bluetooth, nativescript, android-bluetooth

I`m using `nativescript-bluetooth` plugin.

Code:

```
bluetooth.enable().then(function(enabled) {
    setTimeout(function() {
    dialogs.alert({
        title: "Did the user allow enabling Bluetooth by our app?",
        message: enabled ? "Yes" : "No",
        okButtonText: "OK, nice!"
    });
    }, 500);
});
```

When my application started, I see this error in terminal:

`JS: Error in Bluetooth.enable: TypeError: Cannot read property 'startActivityForResult' of undefined`

How fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Most likley you are calling `bluetooth.enable()` before the App has fully initialised. I encounted this and to resolve it I wrapped the function in a timeout:

```
setTimeout(() => enableBluetooth(), 1000)

enableBluetooth() {    
  bluetooth.enable().then(function(enabled) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      dialogs.alert({
        title: "Did the user allow enabling Bluetooth by our app?",
          message: enabled ? "Yes" : "No",
          okButtonText: "OK, nice!"
      });
    }, 500);
  }); 
}
```